# JFreeChart XYPlot with labels

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using an XYPlot in JFreeChart. All the lines on it are XYSeries objects. Both axes are NumberAxis objects. The Y-Axis range is from 0-1, with ticks every .1. Along with displaying the numbers though, I'd like to display text on the Y-Axis, like High/Medium/Low. High would cover .7-1, etc. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some JFreeChart experience, and after a little research I don't have an answer for adding the three labels to the axis.

However, as an alternative approach, you should be able to delineate these three areas on the plot with colors by setting a [MarkerAxisBand](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/MarkerAxisBand.html) for the NumberAxis (using [this method](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setMarkerBand:MarkerAxisBand)).

You could then add interval markers to the MarkerAxisBand to highlight the three areas.

Answer (score 0):

try this ... it can give similare result

[JFreeChart Text Annotations not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262947/jfreechart-text-annotations-not-working)

```
XYTextAnnotation textAnnotaion = new XYTextAnnotation(description, xMid, yMid);
plot.addAnnotation(textAnnotaion);
textAnnotaion.setRotationAngle(90.0);
```